# remote connection to centos7 virtual machine (virtualbox)

Tags: phpmyadmin, virtualbox, centos7

installed centos7 system on virtualbox. The host computer is a linux mint. I in.stalled on centos7 httpd, mariadb, php and phpadmin 7 too. It is ok on centos7 virtual machine.
I would like to connect to phpadmin and mariadb from host computer (linux mint), where I have the IDE to develop my application.

this is centos7 ip address (ip address command):

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000 link/ether 08:00:27:0e:9b:d8 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 85621sec preferred_lft 85621sec
    inet6 fe80::db89:b43e:da69:530d/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

3: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:8d:17:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:8d:17:89 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

This is phpmyadmin.conf on centos7:

```
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
   AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
       Require all granted
 #      Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip 192.168.122.1

#       Require ip 10.0.2.15    
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>

   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
 #    Order Deny,Allow
 #    Deny from All
 #    Allow from 127.0.0.1
 #    Allow from 192.168.122.1

     Order Allow,Deny
     Allow from All

#     Allow from 10.0.2.15
    Allow from 192.168.122.1
     Allow from ::1


   </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     <RequireAny>
  #     Require ip 127.0.0.1
          Require ip 192.168.122.1    
  #      Require ip 10.0.2.15    
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
#     Deny from All

#     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from 192.168.122.1

#     Allow from 10.0.2.15
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>


configuration on virtualbox: 

network
attached to: NAT

adapter type: Intel PRO 1000/MT Desktop 82540EM

promiscuosous: deny

Mac Address: 0800270E9BD8

cable connected: checked

port forwarding configuration: 
name:centos7
protocol:tcp
host ip: empty
host port:3022
guest ip: empty:
guest port:22

file-->preferences-->network
Tab NAT: NatNetwork
 port forwarding configuration: empty
Tab Only Host: ip address 192.168.122.1
```

I tried to connect from host linux mint, but the connection is not OK.
I think that the host machine does not see the centos7 on virtual machine....

Do you any idea?

Thank you...

Answer (score 0):

Did you enable port forwarding for the that applications?

You are using NAT for the networking, without port forwarding you cant connect to the guest operating system

Comment: network configuration on virtualbox: 

attached to: NAT

adapter type: Intel PRO 1000/MT Desktop 82540EM

promiscuosous: deny

Mac Address: 0800270E9BD8

cable connected: checked

port forwarding configuration: 
name:centos7
protocol:tcp
host ip: empty
host port:8080
guest ip: empty:
guest port:80

Comment: Sorry for delay. Each applications will have separate port to connect. maria DB port is 3306. for all the ports you should add port forwarding rules.